# Depth-free Frobenius map computation in $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I read it somewhere that evaluation of Frobenius maps on elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$ is multiplicative depth-free. This boils down to the claim that computation of $a^p$ is depth-free inside $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$. 
This is what I understood,
Since elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^l}$ are polynomials of the form $a_0 + a_1*x + ... + a_{l-1}*x^{l-1}$, let us consider an element $a$.
Now when we compute $a^p$, all the coefficients remain same by Fermat's little theorem, but the positions of these coefficients get shuffled. For e.g. $a_2*x^2 \to a_2*x^{2*p \mod l }$. This means that the exponentiation with $p$ has been reduced to some shifting operations inside the polynomial.
But, how can we say that this exponentiation is depth-free meaning that we can do this with a constant number of mult-gates? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does *depth-free* mean?

Comment: Here, it means we can do $a^p$ with a constant number of multiplication gates whereas if we were to do $a^p$ using regular exponentiation methods, we would require $\log p$ mult-gates

Comment: Okay, … then what are multiplication gates?

Comment: A mult-gate takes in 2 arguments and returns their product as output.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. You are asking about computational properties of the Frobenius, right? What I don’t get it is: Since the prime field $\mathbb F_p$ is fixed, in this scenario the prime $p$ is a constant and so $\log p$ is constant as well, right?

Comment: Yes, $\log p$ is fixed in that way, but I meant that computing $a^p$ inside the extension field mentioned above can be done with a constant number of mult-gates and does not depend on $p$ or $l$.

Comment: Computing the Frobenius is, indeed, easy (it's a linear mapping). But I somehow guess that what you read about had to with [normal bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis). If, instead of a *monomial basis*, like $1,x,x^2,\ldots, x^{\ell-1}$ modulo some chosen primitive polynomial, you present the elements of the field using a basis of the form $\gamma, \gamma^p,\gamma^{p^2},\ldots,\gamma^{p^{\ell-1}}$, then the calculation of Frobenius becomes a cyclic shift of the sequence of coordinates.

Comment: Mind you, something is wrong with your formula. You can't just calculate with exponents modulo $\ell$ like that. At least not always.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes I know I can not always calculate with exponents modulo $l$, just wrote that for an illustration.